# Why am I getting error message "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"?

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have a object `$images` that looks like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 125
            [title] => 131301
            [file_name] => 131301
            [file_ext] => jpg
            [dir] => Adventure/
            [fk_gallery_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 126
            [title] => 181301
            [file_name] => 181301
            [file_ext] => jpg
            [dir] => Adventure/
            [fk_gallery_id] => 1
        )
);
```

Now I want to get the first element in the object:

$obj = $images[0].

This gives me the error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
```

Can anyone tell me why this is not working?

I've also tried `$images[0]->id`, but this is not working either.

Comment: Because you have an object and not an array... like the error message says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$images is not an array, it is an object of the type StdClass (standard class is actually a dummy class). To access class members, you have to use the format

```
$object->membername
```

Unfortunately, 0 is not a valid member name. Hence you cannot use $images->0. The workaround is to use the format

```
$images->{"0"}
```

The following will also work (Depending on your PHP version)

```
$a = 0;
$images->$a;
```

Comment: Yes, $tim-cooper already explained this. But it's not working for me. See my comment.

Comment: my bad. you need to use $images->{"0"}

Comment: Thanks, that worked like a charm. - Actually, I was a bit too quick. The result is the same - I get nothing.

Comment: Try this code. Is it working? `$tmp = json_decode('{"0": [1, 2, 3]}');
print_r($tmp->{"0"});`

Comment: If that works, then the problem is not with the code. Check `$images` and ensure that id is not empty. Are you getting any notices? try setting `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_NOTICE);`

Answer (score 3):

They are class members, therefore you need to access them like this:

```
$obj = $images->{0};
```

See: [Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Comment: Aha.Thanks, I didn't know that. This removes the error. But doing a `print_r($obj)`shows nothing. And `echo $obj->title` also shows nothing.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$obj = $images["0"];
```

or

```
$key = 0;
$obj = $images[ $key ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$a = $image->0;
$id = $a->id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this as the images is also an object and inside one are also objects

```
$images->{0}->id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try
$image->0->id
This might work for your code